# Cannot open database "Inmobiliaria" requested by the login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Buenos dias gente. Antes de formatear mi pc hace unos dias estaba haciendo un proyecto en MVC C# y funcionaba todo perfecto, ahora resulta que obtengo el siguiente error:

> Cannot open database "Inmobiliaria" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'CRONOPIO\Lucas'.
>
> Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web
>   actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información
>   acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot
>   open database "Inmobiliaria" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'CRONOPIO\Lucas'.
>
> Error de código fuente:

```
Línea 35:             //Este ViewBag.lista contiene la lista de los nombres de las imagenes con sus extensiones .jpg
Línea 36:             ViewBag.lista = listaRutaImagenes;
Línea 37:             var myList = await db.Inmobiliaria.ToListAsync();
Línea 38:             return View(myList);
Línea 39:         }

Archivo de origen: D:\MVC\TP_Final3\TPFinal\TPFinal\Controllers\HomeController.cs    Línea: 37
```

Alguien podría darme una mano para ver de que lado viene el problema? 
Saludos y gracias desde ya.

Comment: haz utilizado un cliente de sql, por ejemplo, SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) para comprobar que la autenticación que estás intentando realizar funciona correctamente.

Comment: No. ¿Como podría hacerlo?.

Comment: Primero, ¿tienes instalado el SSMS? o que clientes estás utilizando para realizar sentencias a tu Sql Server

Comment: Asi es. Lo tengo instalado.

Comment: Ingresas a SSMS y en el cuadro de dialogo la informcón que te solicita lo ingresar a partir de la cadena de conexión, por ejemplo: tipo servidor, nombre del servidor, tipo de autenticación, login (usuario) y contraseña.

Comment: Para no extender esto de los comentarios, por favor escribe una respuesta y a partir de ahí te responderé. Te pasare mi connection string y los datos de mi sql a ver si encontramos por donde viene el error.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53084/discussion-between-davlio-and-lucas-david).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lucas

En la PC/Servidor donde hayas instalado tu `Sql Sever` verifica que los servicios se estén ejecutando como los protocolos. Para ello podrías utilizar el Sql Server Configuration Manager (Administrador de configuraciones de SQL Server).

**Verificar servicios:**

En la sección SQL Server Services (Servicios de SQL Server) verifica que los servicios se estén ajecutando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Verificar protocolos:**

En la sección de Protocols for MSSQLSERVER (Protocolos de MSSQLSERVER) verificar que esté activos el TCP/IP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro de los problemas es que quizás el Firewall esté bloqueando el puerto 1433, la fácil comprobación sería con `telnet`.